# How to create clickable magnet URL in discord embeds

Tags: post, rss, discord, webhooks, magnet-uri

In the embed description I have the magnet url `[Link]({{3.rssFields.link}})`. How do I make this clickable? I would like it to open the available torrent client. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know about the bot but discord has made magnet links unclickable for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've had success using a link-shortening service like tinyurl to make magnet links clickable. A `tinyurl.com/xxxxxxxx` link which redirects to a magnet URI is clickable in a Discord embed, and generally seems to open correctly in torrent clients.